# Manipulate and function definition

Tags: manipulate

I have read the documentation, and know the way Initialization works with Manipulate, but I can't seem to understand why this piece of code

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[h[x], {x, -3, 3}]
 , {b, -5, 5}
 , Initialization :> (h[x_] := x + b)]
```

produces a static graph. I know that if I change the function `h[x]` to `h[x_,b_]`, then the `Manipulate` gives a dynamic graph, but I would like the function `h` to have one parameter (instead of two), if possible.

What am I missing here? Thanks, as always, for all help!

Comment: Try `h[x]/.b->b`

Comment: @Kuba: I like this simple method a lot, thanks!

Comment: Since you don't say, I can't comment on your reasons for really wanting `h` to have only one parameter.  But if it were my code, I find it difficult to imagine that I'd be happy with any variant of the one-parameter solution.

Comment: Because `b` is not explicitly present in the body of `Manipulate` it is not being tracked. You need to add `TrackedSymbols :> {b}` to the `Manipulate` options.

Comment: @JohnFultz: I don't quite understand your comment: would you be happy with the one-parameter function h? Can you elaborate why yes/no? Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel I'm thinking of `Manipulate` as a form of `DynamicModule`.  `DynamicModule` does lexical scoping.    It's generally a bad idea to assign a lexically scoped localized variable to a global symbol (as you are assigning `h` in terms of `b`).  It's difficult to understand, it may not do what you want, and the behavior might change depending upon implementational details.  Therefore, I would strongly prefer `DynamicModule` (and `Module`) variables to be passed directly as function arguments without side-effect assignments.

Comment: @Kuba  This works because the expression has a `b` in it and not because of anything `ReplaceAll` does.  Simpler: `Manipulate[ b; Plot[...`.  Cutesy: `... h[x] + 0. b ...`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I must say now it makes sense to me :p Forgive me my fenomenological approach, at least I've not said anything stupid :)

Comment: @Kuba No problemo :)  It's a minor point, but I thought it deserved clarification because the OP said he liked it.  One could use `ReplaceAll` with an expression instead of a function: With the definition `h = x + b0`, then `Plot[h /. b0 -> b,...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this to get the answer in Simon Woods' comment on record.

```
Manipulate[Plot[h[x], {x, -3, 3}],
  {b, -5, 5},
  TrackedSymbols -> {b},
  Initialization :> (h[x_] := x + b)]
```

I think this is the simplest solution to the problem as posed.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `b` is local inside the `Manipulate`. The `Initialization` construct acts just as if the initialization code was executed before the `Manipulate` -- hence is outside its scope. So it only looks like the `b` is inside the scope of the `Manipulate`.

If you really want to define `h` inside the `Manipulate` to have a single argument, you can accomplish it this way:

```
bOld = 100;
Manipulate[ If[bOld != b, h[x_] := x + b; bOld = b;]; 
            Plot[h[x], {x, -3, 3}], {b, -5, 5}]
```

The `bOld` and `If` are used to make sure the function does not continuously retrigger the evaluation and only redefines `h[x]` when needed (i.e., when `b` changes).